# Calculated Column with Current Row Values and Previous Dates in Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I'm trying to get a calculated column (not a measure) that gets the sum of a column based on the values in the current row of that table for dates that are 1 month lagged to the date on the current row.  My table has dates that are the 1st day of every month only .. no other days in the month.  I'm asking the question about DAX; however, I have no problem implementing in M Language in Power Query (actually would probably prefer) if there is a solution that way as well.

I have been able to get a measure to work using something like this..

```
CALCULATE(SUM(AMT), DATEADD(DATECOLUMN, -1, MONTH))
```

But I'd like to be a new column instead.

Assuming the table looks something like this..

```
A    B        C          D     AMT
6    BAC456   5/1/2019   TEST  25
2    EPS123   4/1/2019   TEST  45
2    EPS123   3/1/2019   TEST  65
6    BAC456   4/1/2019   TEST  43
6    BAC456   4/1/2019   TEST  88
7    GRE123   4/1/2019   TEST  90
9    BAC456   4/1/2019   TEST  43
```

I'd like to have another column in this table where the first row would be:

```
A    B         C          D      AMT   NEWCOL
6    BAC456    5/1/2019   TEST   25    131
```

Second row would be:

```
A    B         C          D      AMT   NEWCOL
2    EPS123    4/1/2019   TEST   45    65
```

etc..

In cases where the month column is the first month in the entire table NEWCOL would be 0

Comment: shouldn't the value for row 1 be 174 ?

Comment: No .. A, B and D must all match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `131`, I'm assuming that you are requiring a match on both columns `A` and `B`.

```
NewCol =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[AMT] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[A], Table1[B] ),
    PREVIOUSMONTH ( Table1[C] )
)
```

This sums the column `AMT` keeping the row context of columns `A` and `B` and specifies the previous month as a filter on `C`. Note that this returns a blank for rows that don't have a previous month. If you'd prefer `0` then add `+ 0` after the last closing parenthesis.

---

If `PREVIOUSMONTH` doesn't work, then try this:

```
NewCol =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[AMT] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[A], Table1[B] ),
    Table1[C] = EOMONTH ( EARLIER( Table1[C] ), -2 ) + 1
)
```

For `date = 5/1/2019`, `EOMONTH ( date, -2 )` returns `3/31/2019`. Add one day to get `4/1/2019`.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work this way.. I think the time intelligence functions are predicated on there being a continuous date in the table or a related date dimension table with continuous dates.  Neither of which I have in this scenario.  I'm not very familiar with ALLEXCEPT either, but the pattern is pretty straight forward that you laid out, so I don't believe it's that part that is creating the issue.  Thank you for the response though

Comment: So there is one problem with this that I didn't think about.  I'd like it to handle cases where in the previous month there are records that do not match the current month.  The only way that I can think to do that would be to first Union those rows in with  the current month date and AMT = 0.  Then the above formula would capture these previous amounts in the current month.  Do you know how I could accomplish that?  In SQL it would be ....  [ORIGINAL SET] UNION ALL SELECT A,B, CURRENT_MONTH, D, 0 FROM PREVIOUS_MONTH WHERE A||B||D NOT IN(SELECT A||B||D FROM CURRENT_MONTH)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this easily in a calculated column, you need something like this before writing the final DAX.

```
Month Num = MONTH(MyTable[C])
Month Diff = DATEDIFF(MyTable[C],MAX(MyTable[C]),MONTH)
```

And now you have these Month differences and Month numbers defined, you can write a DAX like this -

```
Amount - New Column = 
Var selectedValue_B = MyTable[B]
Var SelectedValue_MonthDiff = MyTable[Month Diff]
Var out1 = CALCULATE(SUM(MyTable[AMT]), FILTER(ALL(MyTable), MyTable[Month Diff] = SelectedValue_MonthDiff+1 && MyTable[B] = selectedValue_B)) + 0
return out1
```

This makes my table to look something like,

[image]

I have used Var(Variables) in my formula to help you understand what is happening inside the formula.

Kindly accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you

Comment: Does this work for `1/1/2019` looking up `12/1/2018`?

Comment: I should have been more clear. I was attempting to point out that I don't think your measure would generalize to data that spans more than one calendar year.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Get you now. I see it. Updated again. This will help it I think.